# magento categories 1 column layout not working for every category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, grid-layout

in manage categories i have created the following categories/subcategories

- Collections

  - Classic

    - Double Necklaces
    - Necklaces
    - Bracelets
  - New York

    - Necklaces
    - Bracelets

i have set 1 page layout in custom design

why is it that it works for

-collections

-collections/classic/double necklaces

-collections/new-york/necklaces

-collections/new-york/bracelets

And the others

-collections/classic

-collections/classic/necklaces

-collections/classic/bracelets

-collections/new-york

it does not work... all have same settings but these last categories/subcategories show the sidebar wit layerednav

what can i be doing wrong???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a config issue. Triple check all the settings are the same in the Category admin and take special care while looking at the Design tab and also in Display settings.
Is Anchor should be set to No and all the inputs related to Design should be blank.

Comment: ;-) all settings were exactly the same.

the only thing that worked was to delete the categories and re-create them... now it does what it should do

Comment: Please add that as an answer and mark this question as solved.